# I only have two presets for ffmpeg x264 in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ffmpeg, natty, preset

I'me trying to install (compile) ffmpeg for ubuntu 11.04 by following this guide:

https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

Overall it works. Except for some errors with checkinstall due to numbering, which i resolved with this:

http://judsonsnotes.com/notes/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=3&Itemid=54&limitstart=40

I'd say it was installed ok.

But when trying to encode some video with -vpre lossless_slow i get this error:

```
File for preset lossless_slow not found.
```

And in fact it doesn't exists. All i have is this:

```
/usr/local/share/ffmpeg:
libvpx-1080p50_60.ffpreset
libvpx-1080p.ffpreset
libvpx-360p.ffpreset
libvpx-720p50_60.ffpreset
libvpx-720p.ffpreset
libx264-ipod320.ffpreset
libx264-ipod640.ffpreset
```

Where are all the other presets ? in google usually people have many more presets than i do. What did i do wrong ?

From this post i'd say that they shopuld be there: http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=4b82e3cedcfc9871671bb613cd979de6995dcb4e

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FFmpeg now accesses the x264 internal presets instead of using text files to emulate them. This is easier to maintain and use. Now you must use the `-preset` option instead of `-vpre`. Current presets are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow, placebo. Ignore placebo as it is a joke and a waste of time.

CRF Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Two-Pass Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset fast -b:v 555k -pass 1 -an -f mp4 - && \
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset fast -b:v 555k -pass 2 -c:a libfaac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

These examples come from the [x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) community wiki page at ffmpeg.org.